# QPid with JMS. Unable to create/bind queue with jndi

Tags: jms, jndi, qpid

Using: qpid-broker 0.32, qpid-jms-client-0.3.0

Hello.  New user of the AMQP protocol.  I'm attempting to create and bind a queue to an already existing fanout exchange through JNDI, then connect through a JMS client.  If I create the exchange, the queue, and bind it directly from the webPortal everything works fine.  If I create just the exchange through the webPortal then use my jndi properties file to create and bind the queue, it's unable to resolve and I get a javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException.  What am I doing wrong?

I have setup a custom fanout exchange called TEST_FANOUT_EXCHANGE on localhost:5672.  Virtual hosts are all default.

My jndi.properties file is:

java.naming.factory.initial = org.apache.qpid.jms.jndi.JmsInitialContextFactory
connectionfactory.qpidConnectionfactory = amqp://localhost:5672

queue.fanoutQueue = messagequeue
destination.fanoutExchange = fanout://TEST_FANOUT_EXCHANGE//messagequeue?durable='true'&autodelete='true'&exclusive='false'

Java code is as follows:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
InputStream input = new FileInputStream("conf/jndi.properties");
properties.load(input);

Context context = new InitialContext(properties); 
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory
                = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup("qpidConnectionfactory"); 
Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection("guest","guest"); 
            connection.start(); 
Session session=connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Queue destination = (Queue) context.lookup("fanoutQueue");

MessageConsumer messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
```

---

According to the documentation, if the exchange or queue does not exist, it will get created and binded automatically.  So why isn't this happening?

Thank you!

Dennis

Comment: Which code line throws the exception?

Comment: Also why are you sending a message to a specific queue? The whole point of fanout is you send the message to the exchange which then automatically gets routed to every queue that is bound to that fanout exchange. Can you show how you are creating your exchanges and queues?